# Swing the rope object through joint

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I want to do swing the rope in unity using a fixed joint. Mostly it works but when I leave the rope at that time physics of the rope becomes unstructured. What is the solution for this?

Comment: Please clarify - when does it not work, and what does "physics of the rope become unstructured" mean?

Comment: I think you mean "unstable"?  If so, the usual way to deal with this is to add some damping -- e.g. reduce all the velocities by 5% each frame.

Comment: Look, Physics of rope is, i m giving a rigid body with fixed rotation and fixed position of z and i m swing my rope with the use of rotate/angular velocity as left to right and right to left.

When my player joint with rope at that time i m adding "fixed joint" between player and rope at the same time problem is arrived.

1) my rope speed will be stopped quickly and i never forced it again  same as earlier  i try my best using addforce,velocity and translate also.

Thank you GrandMasterFlush